# How to start from the top of a select tag's options when an option is selected?

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

I have a list of options in my select tag, and one of them has the selected attribute. When you click on the option, it opens the select dropdown and scrolls down to the option with that selected attribute, like so.
[Dropdown One](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6qxf.png)

Is there a way to have it so when you click the select dropdown, it doesn't scroll at all like so, without removing the selected attribute?

[Dropdown Two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsMJt.png)

Here is my code.

```
<select id="number_id">
<option value>Select</option>
<option value="A">1</option>
<option value="B">2</option>
<option value="C">3</option>
<option value="D">4</option>
<option value="E">5</option>
<option value="F">6</option>
<option value="G">7</option>
<option value="H">8</option>
<option value="I">9</option>
<option value="J">10</option>
<option value="K">11</option>
<option value="L">12</option>
<option value="M">13</option>
<option value="N">14</option>
<option value="O">15</option>
</select>
```